# SQL - How to get a user's favorite posts title from StackExchange Database

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I am working on a project analyzing Stackoverflow's user's behaviors and I need to get data from the stackoverflow, one of the data I need to get is to get a user's favorite posts title from stackexchange Database. Right now, I only figured out how to get the user's favorite information as following:

```
select VT.name, U.DisplayName
from VoteTypes VT, Votes V, Users U
where VT.Id = 5 and
           VT.Id = V.VoteTypeId and
           U.Id = V.UserId and 
           U.Id = '85597'
```

I think the next step is to find the posts the User voted, then match the userId. But I don't know if it is a right step to do. And I could not find any connection between a User's vote and a question post

Comment: no-one should be joining using comma separated tables any longer, over 25 years have elapsed since explicit join syntax was formalized. time to change.

Comment: @Used_By_Already what do I change to? As I am taking a database course right now, and it taught me to use in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
      vt.name
    , u.DisplayName
FROM VoteTypes vt 
   , Votes v        <<<<<<<<< not good
   , Users u        <<<<<<<<< not good
WHERE vt.Id = 5
AND vt.Id = v.VoteTypeId  <<<<<<<<< join predicate (vt = v)
AND u.Id = v.UserId       <<<<<<<<< join predicate (u = v)
AND u.Id = '85597
```

Just *STOP using commas between table names*.'That simple step will force you to more carefully consider the joins.

Move the join predicates to the table they refer to AFTER an **ON**. (Join predicates refer to different tables either side of an operator such as equals.)

```
SELECT
      vt.name
    , u.DisplayName
FROM VoteTypes vt
   , Votes v ON vt.Id = v.VoteTypeId
   , Users u ON u.Id = v.UserId
WHERE vt.Id = 5
AND 
AND 
AND u.Id = '85597'
```

Replace those dreaded commas with appropriate join type, and tidy-up.

```
SELECT
      vt.name
    , u.DisplayName
FROM VoteTypes vt
INNER JOIN Votes v ON vt.Id = v.VoteTypeId
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.Id = v.UserId
WHERE vt.Id = 5
AND u.Id = '85597'
```

**Done.**

If your course is using old syntax; consider getting a better course.

Comment: Thank you for you correction! I am wondering if you could also help me with the content?